# How to create a column of arrays whose values are coming from one column and their length is coming from another column in pyspark dataframes?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In a pyspark dataframe, I need to create a new column of ArrayType(StringType()) whose values are coming from a StringType() column and their lengths are coming from the length of another ArrayType(StringType()) column. Kind of like an array_repeat with dynamic length.

**input**:

```
+-------------+-------------+
|col1         |col2         |
+-------------+-------------+
|[1,2]        |‘a’          |
|[1,2,3]      |‘b’          |
+-------------+-------------+
```

**output**:

```
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|col1         |col2         |col3            |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|[1,2]        |‘a’          |['a’,‘a’]       |
|[1,2,3]      |‘b’          |['b’,’b’,’b’]   |
+-------------+----------- -+----------------+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative-

### Load the test data provided

```scala
val df = spark.sql(
      """
        |select col1, col2
        |from values
        | (array(1, 2), 'a'),
        | (array(1, 2, 3), 'b')
        | T(col1, col2)
      """.stripMargin)
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---------+----+
      * |col1     |col2|
      * +---------+----+
      * |[1, 2]   |a   |
      * |[1, 2, 3]|b   |
      * +---------+----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- col1: array (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
      * |-- col2: string (nullable = false)
      */
```

### Alternative-1

```scala
    // alternative-1
    df.withColumn("col3", expr("array_repeat(col2, size(col1))"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---------+----+---------+
      * |col1     |col2|col3     |
      * +---------+----+---------+
      * |[1, 2]   |a   |[a, a]   |
      * |[1, 2, 3]|b   |[b, b, b]|
      * +---------+----+---------+
      */
```

### Alternative-2

```scala
    // alternative-2
    df.withColumn("col3", expr(s"TRANSFORM(col1, x -> col2)"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---------+----+---------+
      * |col1     |col2|col3     |
      * +---------+----+---------+
      * |[1, 2]   |a   |[a, a]   |
      * |[1, 2, 3]|b   |[b, b, b]|
      * +---------+----+---------+
      */
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_repeat` + `size`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([[[1,2],'a'], [[1,2,3], 'b']], ['col1', 'col2'])

df.withColumn('col3', f.array_repeat('col2', f.size('col1'))).show()

+---------+----+---------+
|     col1|col2|     col3|
+---------+----+---------+
|   [1, 2]|   a|   [a, a]|
|[1, 2, 3]|   b|[b, b, b]|
+---------+----+---------+
```

If in any case this doesn't work, you can write a udf to do this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

@f.udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
def repeat_sizeof(col1, col2):
    return [col1] * len(col2)

df.withColumn('col3', repeat_sizeof('col2', 'col1')).show()

+---------+----+---------+
|     col1|col2|     col3|
+---------+----+---------+
|   [1, 2]|   a|   [a, a]|
|[1, 2, 3]|   b|[b, b, b]|
+---------+----+---------+
```

Comment: I have tried that, but I get “column is not iterable” error.

Comment: What's your spark version? Tested this works in spark 3

Comment: I’m on 2.4. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, thought it would work as well. If it doesn't then you might need to do this with a UDF.